# What does the term "Urban Legend" mean?

Tags: etymology

I heard a great story the other day about a guy with a bloody hook for a hand - but then, when I retold it to my kids at bedtime my Au Pair informed me that it was just a silly Urban Legend.  What does she mean by that?